# Would this type of construction be considered pleonastic?

Tags: writing-style

I'm talking about the combination of `such a` and `very` in one nominal group:

> He is such a very remarkable man.

When broken down into its emphatic constituents, we get:

> a. He is such a remarkable man.

---

> b. He is very remarkable.

Do `such a` and `very` semantically annul each other into a pleonasm?

Comment: You give a good example of tautology. *My Big Fat Greek Wedding* is, too, and the words don't cancel each other, but at least it's funny for its clutter.

Comment: As @Yosef implies, there is a school of thought that believes pleonasm is always an error. But these people need to look the word up: << _pleonasm_
mass noun: 
The use of more words than are necessary to convey meaning (e.g. see with one's eyes), either as a fault of style or for emphasis [or other style effect] >>. [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pleonasm)]

Comment: Edwin, if you offered that as an answer, I would vote for it.